# presto insert overwrite with escape

Tags: insert, escaping, overwrite, presto

I am using insert overwrite in presto to load my orc table.In my select query I have ESCAPE , and my script throws an error.Anyone knows if insert overwrite supports escape in the query?If it does not any suggestions?

```
CREATE external TABLE tgt
(
`traffic_source` String
)
stored as orc
LOCATION 's3://bucket/folder/orc/';


insert overwrite table tgt 
select 
case when 
col1 like '%\_ppc%' ESCAPE '\' then 'AA'
else 'BB' end as traffic_source from src;
```

> Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line
>   4:20 missing KW_THEN at 'ESCAPE' near ''%_ppc%'' in expression
>   specification (state=42000,code=40000)

Comment: hive.support.quoted.identifiers=none;

Comment: "using insert overwrite in presto to .." -- `INSERT OVERWRITE` is Hive's HQL, not something Presto can understand. Are you running these statements in Hive actually?

Comment: I tried to run it in hive, however I understand hive does not support much, so I switched it to presto which is working fine.

Answer (score -1):

INSERT OVERWRITE is already supported in Presto : https://www.ebyhr.org/2019/04/insert-overwrite-in-presto.html

Comment: The link refers to a private page.

Comment: Presto does not support this. It only has `INSERT` not `INSERT OVERWRITE`.
https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/insert.html
But e.g. the hive connector has a `hive.insert-existing-partitions-behavior` config property, that would let `INSERT`s run with overwrite behavior.

Comment: Vajk Hermecz, this is technically incorrect as you can follow the link I have posted and verify Presto does support the OVERWRITE mode... through a connector but so what ?